# flutter freezed :Could not generate `toJson` code for `data` because of type

Tags: flutter, freezed

I am trying to create my model by freezed and json_serializable :

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'language_response_model.freezed.dart';
part 'language_response_model.g.dart';

@freezed
abstract class LanguageResourceResponseModel
    with _$LanguageResourceResponseModel {
  const factory LanguageResourceResponseModel({
    required String id,
    required List<ResourceDataModel> data,
  }) = _LanguageResourceResponseModel;

  factory LanguageResourceResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LanguageResourceResponseModelFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
abstract class ResourceDataModel {
  const factory ResourceDataModel({
    required String key,
    required String value,
  }) = _ResourceDataModel;

  factory ResourceDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ResourceDataModelFromJson(json);
}
```

but I got this error :

```
Could not generate `toJson` code for `data` because of type `ResourceDataModel`.
package:test/splash/data/models/language_response_model.freezed.dart:144:33
    ╷
144 │   final List<ResourceDataModel> data;
    │                                 ^^^^
    ╵
[INFO] Running build completed, took 2.5s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 189ms

[SEVERE] Failed after 2.7s
```

What is the problem?

```
dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0
  json_serializable: ^6.0.1
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.1
  freezed: ^0.15.1+1
  freezed_annotation: ^0.15.0
```

Comment: You either need to provide a toJson and fromJson with the JsonKey annotation or implement a JsonConverter class. https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#fromjson---classes-with-multiple-constructors showed here too just scroll a bit down

Comment: By freezed you just need to implement FromJson , Where is to json ?@MDIsmailAlamKhan

Comment: With these changes, Freezed will automatically ask json_serializable to generate all the necessary fromJson/toJson.

Comment: `ResourceDataModel` is annotated with `@freezed` but doesn't mix in `_$ResourceDataModel`.

Comment: Ops, you are right. It was  my mistake . Please write answer I check you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ResourceDataModel` is a `@freezed`-annotated class, so it needs to mix in `_$ResourceDataModel`.

```dart
@freezed
abstract class ResourceDataModel with _$ResourceDataModel {
  // ...
}
```

Without that mixin, `ResourceDataModel` does not contain a `toJson()` method, and thus `LanguageResourceResponseModel.toJson()` cannot serialize a `List<ResourceDataModel>`.